# Insertar registro en la base de datos desde aplicación empresarial

Tags: json, base-de-datos, rest, java-ee

Estoy haciendo una práctica y me he quedado pillado en la parte de insertar en la base de datos, os comento

Estoy utilizando persistence para todo esto, he creado los rest y las clases entities necesarias así como un pool de conexiones y todo eso, es mas, todo el tema de conexion a la base de datos funciona porque hay otras partes del programa en las que cojo los datos de la base de datos y me los carga bien asi es que la conexion funciona jejeje. Una vez hecho esto, tengo un faces-flow con un .java en el que voy guardando los campos para insertar en la base de datos (concretamente los datos de una entrada para un concierto). Una vez hecho esto, hago una llamada a una clase MessageBodyWriter para parsear a JSON los datos que tengo para hacer una llamada a EntradaFacadeRest y hacer la inserción en la base de datos pero al hacerlo me da error. He estado haciendo algo de debug y los datos llegan perfectamente al MessageBodyWriter.

Os muestro el código:

> Clase java del faces-flow:

```
//Arriba de esto solo hay declaraciones de las variables con los get y los set
Client clientEvento , clientEntrada;
WebTarget targetEvento , targetEntrada;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    clientEvento = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    clientEntrada = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    targetEvento = clientEvento.target("http://localhost:8080/Eventizer/webresources/com.g1.eventizer.entities.evento");
    targetEntrada = clientEntrada.target("http://localhost:8080/Eventizer/webresources/com.g1.eventizer.entities.entrada");
//Esta URI funciona. Si hago con postman un get me muestra las entradas que he metido yo a pelo en la base de datos con lo cual la URI esta bien puesta :)
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    clientEvento.close();
    clientEntrada.close();
}
public void addEntrada() {
Entrada e = new Entrada();
QR = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

e.setIdEntrada(1);
e.setPrecio(precio);
e.setFechaCompra(new Date()); //Cogemos el momento en el que se ha efectuado la compra
e.setQr(QR);
e.setEvento(IdEvento);
e.setPropietario(12);

targetEntrada.register(EntradaWriter.class)
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(e, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

> EntradaWriter.class

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EntradaWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Entrada> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Entrada.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Entrada t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Entrada e, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("WRITER!!!!");
        System.out.println("ID: "+e.getIdEntrada());
        System.out.println("Precio: "+e.getPrecio());
        System.out.println("FechaCompra: "+sdf.format(e.getFechaCompra()));
        System.out.println("QR: "+e.getQr());
        System.out.println("Evento: "+e.getEvento());
        System.out.println("Propietario: "+e.getPropietario());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        JsonGenerator gen = Json.createGenerator(entityStream);

            gen.writeStartObject()
                    .write("IdEntrada", e.getIdEntrada())
                    .write("Precio", e.getPrecio())
                    .write("FechaCompra", sdf.format(e.getFechaCompra()))
                    .write("QR", e.getQr())
                    .write("Evento", e.getEvento())
                    .write("Propietario", e.getPropietario())
                    .writeEnd();
            gen.flush();
        }
    }
```

> EntradaReader.class (No se si será necesario pero lo añado por si
>   acaso)

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EntradaReader implements MessageBodyReader<Entrada> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Entrada.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Entrada readFrom(Class<Entrada> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Entrada entrada = new Entrada();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(entityStream);

        while (parser.hasNext()) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
                case KEY_NAME:
                    String key = parser.getString();
                    parser.next();
                    switch (key) {
                        case "idEntrada":
                            entrada.setIdEntrada(parser.getInt());
                            System.out.println("READER--> idEntrada: " + parser.getInt());
                            break;
                        case "fechaCompra": {
                            try {
                                entrada.setFechaCompra(sdf.parse(parser.getString()));
                                System.out.println("READER--> FechaCompra: " +sdf.parse(parser.getString()));

                            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(EntradaReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                System.out.println("ERROR PARSSEO ENTRADA-READER");
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                        case "precio":
                            entrada.setPrecio(Float.parseFloat(parser.getString()));
                            System.out.println("READER--> Precio: " + Float.parseFloat(parser.getString()));

                            break;
                        case "qr":
                            entrada.setQr(parser.getString());
                            System.out.println("READER--> QR: " + parser.getString());

                            break;
                        case "propietario":
                            entrada.setPropietario(parser.getInt());
                            System.out.println("READER--> Propietario: " + parser.getInt());

                            break;
                        case "evento":
                            entrada.setEvento(parser.getInt());
                            System.out.println("READER--> Evento: " + parser.getInt());

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return entrada;
    }
}
```

> EntradaFacadeRest.class

```
@Stateless
@Named
@Path("com.g1.eventizer.entities.entrada")
public class EntradaFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Entrada> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.g1_Eventizer_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntradaFacadeREST() {
        super(Entrada.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(Entrada entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Entrada entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Entrada find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Entrada> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Entrada> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

> ERROR AL EJECUTAR EL METODO **addEntrada()**

```
Información:   ----------------------------------------
Información:   WRITER!!!!
Información:   ID: 1
Información:   Precio: 57.98
Información:   FechaCompra: 2019-05-09
Información:   QR: 8e5b3849-4b95-4016-9c81-09022a7d7d80
Información:   Evento: 2
Información:   Propietario: 12
Información:   ----------------------------------------
Advertencia:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB EntradaFacadeREST, method: public void com.g1.eventizer.rest.EntradaFacadeREST.create(com.g1.eventizer.entities.Entrada)
Advertencia:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4600)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2078)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy369.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.g1.eventizer.rest.__EJB31_Generated__EntradaFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: One or more Bean Validation constraints were violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event: prePersist for class: com.g1.eventizer.entities.Entrada. Please refer to the embedded constraint violations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4412)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4389)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at com.g1.eventizer.rest.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:26)
    at com.g1.eventizer.rest.EntradaFacadeREST.create(EntradaFacadeREST.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4820)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:824)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4792)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4780)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 62 more
```

Como véis los datos llegan al MessageBodyWriter correctamente pero a la hora de meterlos en la base de datos... BOOM!! Explota todo y no entiendo por qué. Espero haberme explicado y que puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias y un saludo a todos!!!

Comment: Ya checaste bien la traza?? creo que es muy explicita en estas partes:`Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: One or more Bean Validation constraints were violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event: prePersist for class: com.g1.eventizer.entities.Entrada. Please refer to the embedded constraint violations for details.`-------------------------------------------------------------------------`at com.g1.eventizer.rest.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:26)
    at com.g1.eventizer.rest.EntradaFacadeREST.create(EntradaFacadeREST.java:44)`

Comment: Sii, si que la he revisado pero no entiendo a que puede deberse ese error porque en otra práctica que hicimos está igual y si que funciona :(

Comment: Se violaron una o más restricciones de Validación de Bean al ejecutar la Validación Automática de Bean en el evento de devolución de llamada